# Bind Configuration

Tags: dns, bind, acl, named

I updated my bind server from `9.11.8` to `9.11.13`.The installation procedure was fine. And I installed it perfectly. But when I tried to start bind server then it failed every time.Then I view the message of `/var/log/messages` and I found following error:

`/etc/named.conf:16: '127.0.0.1/8':address/prefix length mismatch '8'`

Then I checked the `named.conf` file and there I saw I use `127.0.0.1/8` this IP address in the `acl "trust-net"` section.

But when I run `9.11.8` the setting was same and that run perfectly.
But after installation bind `9.11.13`,I can't start my bind server.

Major Information:
-`centos5.4(final)`

acl conf:

acl trust-net `{ 127.0.0.1/8;}`;

Please help me out from this situation.

Comment: Did you try to run `named-checkconf`? Also you should probably use `127.0.0.0/8` and not `127.0.0.1/8`. Or just `127/8` in fact.

Comment: I run named-checkconf .But it gave that error which I explain in description.But why I cannot use 127.0.0.1/8?When I run previous version of bind It didn't give any error.That was run perfectly.What is the problem?

Comment: Did you try with `127.0.0.0/8` or `127/8` and does it works in your case? Also note that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.